# Gecode element constraint seems to hang with large seperation between elements

Tags: c++, gecode

I am just getting started with Gecode element constraints. It seems to hang when the list elements are too far apart.

Here is the full program to demonstrate the issue, with a few knobs (MACROS) to change the behavior.

1. The issue seems to manifest only when using INT_VAL_RAND, INT_VAL_MIN is working fine (Controllable with Knob USE_MIN_BRANCHING=0/1)
2. If I force Gecode to use only one element, it is again working fine (Controllable with Knob FORCE_SINGLE_IDX=0/1)
3. If I use relatively close ranges, it's working fine (Controllable with Knob DELTA=Say Powers of 10)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <gecode/int.hh>
#include <gecode/search.hh>
#include <gecode/minimodel.hh>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned int uint_t;
using namespace Gecode;

class Class : public Space {
public:
  IntVar a, idx;
  inline static IntArgs ranges;
  inline static vector<int> idxes;

  Class() :
  a(*this, Int::Limits::min, Int::Limits::max),
  idx(*this, IntSet(&idxes[0], idxes.size())) {
    if (USE_MIN_BRANCHING) {
      branch(*this, a, INT_VAL_MIN());
      branch(*this, idx, INT_VAL_MIN());
    } else {
      Rnd rndA(rand());
      branch(*this, a, INT_VAL_RND(rndA));

      Rnd rndIdx(rand());
      branch(*this, idx, INT_VAL_RND(rndIdx));
    }

    rel(*this, a >= element(ranges, idx));
    rel(*this, a <= element(ranges, idx + 1));
    if (FORCE_SINGLE_IDX) {
      rel(*this, idx == 2);
    }
  }

  void show() {
    for (IntVarRanges i(a); i(); ++i) {
      cout << "a: " << i.min() << ".." << i.max() << "\n" << flush;
    }
    for (IntVarRanges i(idx); i(); ++i) {
      cout << "idx: " << i.min() << ".." << i.max() << "\n" << flush;
    }
    cout << "-----------------\n" << flush;
  }

  // search support
  Class(Class& s) : Space(s) {
    a.update(*this, s.a);
    idx.update(*this, s.idx);
  }

  virtual Space* copy(void) {
    return new Class(*this);
  }

  // print solution
  void print() {
    cout << idx.val() << " " << a.val() << "\n" << flush;
  }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    srand(1);

    unsigned int from;
    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
      from = 1000000000 + i * DELTA;
      Class::ranges << from;
      Class::ranges << from + 7;
      Class::idxes.push_back(i << 1);
      cout << "" << from << "\n" << flush;
    }

    // Print all solutions in MIN branching
    Class* c = new Class;
    c->show();
    DFS<Class> e(c);
    delete c;

    while (c = e.next()) {
      c->print();
      delete c;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To run (Assuming an envvar GECODE_HOME pointing to the GECODE installation)

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O3 ./bla.cc -DDELTA=1000000000 -DUSE_MIN_BRANCHING=0 -DFORCE_SINGLE_IDX=0 -I $GECODE_HOME/include -L$GECODE_HOME/lib -lgecodesearch -lgecodeminimodel -lgecodeint -lgecodekernel -lgecodesupport ; ./a.out
```

Here is the summary of the results

[image]

Why is GECODE unable to optimize for large numbers just with INT_VAL_RAND? What am I missing?

PS: The example might not make sense to use a constraint solver, but please note that it is stripped down to demonstrate the issue and there are more variables involved in actual constraint.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't do `typedef unsigned int uint_t;`. If you need a plain unsigned integer whose size isn't important, use `unsigned`. If you want an unsigned integer of a specific size then use e.g. the standard `uint32_t`. If you want to create an alias to get a more semantically relevant name, then use a better name.

Comment: On another couple of unrelated notes, please don't use `rand`, C++ have a much better [PRGN library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Also don't do any work in your class constructors, they should do bare-bones initialization and really nothing more. Don't use pointers if you can avoid it, and when you need to use pointers (for example for polymorphism) then use e.g. `std::unique_ptr` instead of managing it yourself. Also please use better names for your classes and variables, it will make the code much easier to read, understand, debug, and maintain.

Comment: Understood and agreed. The thing is this is not production code. Unfortunately, this is the minimal code to demonstrate the issue. So wanted to reduce the number of lines of code and dependencies as much as possible.